# 3.75G usb modem, steady blue light, no detection on computer

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, modem

It's a 3.75G HSDPA 7.2Mbps Usb Modem. Shows steady blue light on connection. No Autorun. No detection on Computer. No display in Disk Managment. There seems to be no trace of action anywhere from the modem on the computer. Just a steady blue light. Same occurence on my Windows 7 and another Windows 10. Drivers installed. Other modem of same model worked earlier today. What could be wrong with this one? Please help. Share your thoughts.

Comment: "No display in Disk Managment" why do you expect a USB modem to display in Disk Management?

Comment: Your question is sadly lacking in information. Operating System? Make/model of modem? What have you tried so far? Have you installed any drivers? Please [edit] the question to include this essential information.

Comment: And please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Have you tried different USB ports?

Comment: Yes I have, all 3!